# How to remove duplication with keep first event only, but only apply on one category on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

How to remove duplication with keep first event only, but only apply on one category on pandas.

There's any two categories on `event_name` column, `process_now` and `fast_order`, but the remove duplication have some specialty:
1. remove duplication only on `fast_order` category
2. If `fast_order` appear in multiple consecutive, only keep one in every consecutive (not every user id) 
3. remove duplication is keep the first entry appear

Data

```
User_id   event_name        timestamp
1         process_now       08:00:01
1         process_now       08:00:02
1         process_now       08:00:03
1         fast_order        08:00:04
1         fast_order        08:00:05
1         process_now       08:00:06
2         process_now       08:00:01
2         process_now       08:00:02
2         fast_order        08:00:03
2         fast_order        08:00:04
2         fast_order        08:00:05
2         process_now       08:00:06
2         fast_order        08:00:07
2         fast_order        08:00:08
2         process_now       08:00:09
```

What I need to show is

```
User_id   Event_name        timestamp
1         process_now       08:00:01
1         process_now       08:00:02
1         process_now       08:00:03
1         fast_order        08:00:04
1         process_now       08:00:06
2         process_now       08:00:01
2         process_now       08:00:02
2         fast_order        08:00:03
2         process_now       08:00:06
2         fast_order        08:00:07
2         process_now       08:00:09
```

How suppose I doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) per 2 columns with get consecutive groups, inverse condition and cchain by `|` for bitwise `OR` with condition for test if not equal `fast_order`:

```
g = df['event_name'].ne(df['event_name'].shift()).cumsum()
df = df[df['event_name'].ne('fast_order') | ~df.assign(g=g).duplicated(['User_id','g'])]
print (df)
    User_id   event_name timestamp
0         1  process_now  08:00:01
1         1  process_now  08:00:02
2         1  process_now  08:00:03
3         1   fast_order  08:00:04
5         1  process_now  08:00:06
6         2  process_now  08:00:01
7         2  process_now  08:00:02
8         2   fast_order  08:00:03
11        2  process_now  08:00:06
12        2   fast_order  08:00:07
14        2  process_now  08:00:09
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.assign(g=g))
    User_id   event_name timestamp  g
0         1  process_now  08:00:01  1
1         1  process_now  08:00:02  1
2         1  process_now  08:00:03  1
3         1   fast_order  08:00:04  2
5         1  process_now  08:00:06  3
6         2  process_now  08:00:01  3
7         2  process_now  08:00:02  3
8         2   fast_order  08:00:03  4
11        2  process_now  08:00:06  5
12        2   fast_order  08:00:07  6
14        2  process_now  08:00:09  7
```

---

```
print (df.assign(g=g).duplicated(['User_id','g']))
0     False
1      True
2      True
3     False
5     False
6     False
7      True
8     False
11    False
12    False
14    False
dtype: bool

print (~df.assign(g=g).duplicated(['User_id','g']))
0      True
1     False
2     False
3      True
5      True
6      True
7     False
8      True
11     True
12     True
14     True
dtype: bool
```